# Max Width of UITabbarItem on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

what's the maximal width of each item on iPAD e.g. on 5 items. I know on iPad is on left and right corner some space, but how big is width on each item? (On iPHone it's easy to calculate..but how is it on iPad?

Comment: You found out or not? Isn't my answer help you??

Comment: I'm sry, i forget to answer, now here: Thank you very much for your answer but that wasn't what I needed...But i've found the right way..just look at my answer...

Comment: just waiting some to post my answer...

Comment: Its ok. You asked how big is width of each item? **So I gave answer for what exactly you asked. But not exactly what you think.** Anyway when you can, then answer yourself to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a screen shot from new **Mobile HIG(Human Interface Guidelines)**. From this, you can get the **size of the tabbar icon**. It is **approximate** only. But you can have this as a reference and calculate the width depend on the number of items. For your 5 items,

**In iPad standard, its 30 * 5 = 150 px**

**In iPad retina, its 60 * 5 = 300 px**

[image]

Comment: excuse me but I'm not a idiot :D - i know the HIG. But if you set items with 60x60 you know it loooks very ugly. So my question was how i have to set the tabbar images to show it, maybe over the whole width or maybe variabel...i will try it out now on myself...

Comment: No offense always.You asked a question. And I gave you what you asked for. Thats it. Ok lets come to your point. You said its ugly. Are you saying the graphics is ugly?? If you can little more specific. For tabbar icon design we need to have an image in the center of the image and other portions should be look as transparent. So that it will look good. Why only 60 x 60 is ugly anyway??